# XML some parts not visible when importing to Excel

Tags: xml, excel, excel-formula

I have imported my XML file to Excel and while some columns look just like they should, some of them have the value "Table".

Columns that aren't correct are: photo url, category id, subcategory id. - I hope this information may be useful in

[image]

Comment: Any sample of the XML file?

Comment: How are you importing?